# React Native Jest coverage output affected by how ES6 module is exported

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

I have a simple React Native button component which has its own `index.js` and `styles.js` files. This is how `styles.js` looks like:

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    borderRadius: 2
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: 2
  }
});
```

When I write a simple unit test for this button component, I see the code coverage on `styles.js` as `0%`. However, Jest did not throw any error saying it does not match the `80%` coverage threshold I configured.

Out of curiosity, I assigned the StyleSheet to a constant and exported it instead, resulting in below version of `styles.js`:

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    borderRadius: 2
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: 2
  }
});

export default styles;
```

This time Jest coverage report showed `100%`. What could be the reasoning behind this? Am I doing anything wrong, or missing something?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I used **const** and **default** export.
In result I got 100% coverage.

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    position: 'relative',
  },
});

export default styles;
```

P.S. When I use export without const, my test complete with **0%** coverage